# How to remove newline from dynamic strings

Tags: c, string

I have this segment of code which takes in input various strings. They don't have to have newline in the end, I need them one next to another because I'm writing them on a CSV file. I put this on a while

```
    do {
        printf("Put the ingredient:\n");
        fgets(recipe.ingredients[j], 30, stdin);
        len = strlen(recipe.ingredients[j]) + 1;
        recipe.ingredients[len] == "\0";
        fprintf(fbr, "%s,", recipe.ingredients[j]);
        j++;
        counter++;
        printf("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)");
        fgets(sentinel, 4, stdin);
    } while(strcmp("yes", sentinel) == 0);
```

The problem is, the first string I get in input doesn't have the newline char since I put that condition. I tried both adding and subtracting `1` to the length but in both cases I have just the first string without the newline and the others have the newline anyway. I thought that by replacing the newline character with the null terminator I would solve my problem but maybe I'm missing something. Any hint to solve this? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but these two lines:`len = strlen(recipe.ingredients[j]) + 1;
recipe.ingredients[len] == "\0";` do not do what you think they do.

Comment: Another possibility is `strtok(recipe.ingredients[j], "\n");`

Comment: Is `recipe.ingredients` an array of `char`, a pointer to `char`, an array of arrays, or an array of pointers?  It's not completely clear based on the way you're using it.

Comment: @SteveSummit it's a `char**` type

Comment: @SteveSummit Anyway I solved it with a strtok, thanks a lot

Comment: the important hint that @SteveSummit was giving you is that you have an extra `=` sign in the supposed assignment statement.

Comment: @bruceg Oh my, I just noticed now, thank you too

Comment: But it's more than that: If the assignment of `'\0'` was supposed to overwrite the newline, and given that we've just computed `len = strlen(recipe.ingredients[j])`, then the assignment we want is probably something like `recipe.ingredients[j][len] = "\0"`.  Simply fixing the `==`, and changing it to `recipe.ingredients[len] = "\0"`, does something completely different.  (If, that is, `recipe.ingredients` is "two dimensional", as it sounds like it is.)

Comment: @Goner if `recipe.ingredients` is `char **`, it will be important to have set it up, rather carefully, to point at validly-allocated pointer(s) to the several different ingredients (indexed by `j`).  If that code's not right, it's going to compound any problems you're having as you try to read lines, locate newlines, and suppress them.

Comment: @SteveSummit I've already allocated them dinamically, I just had the problem with the newline in the end, in fact when I didn't allocated them correctly I had many segmentation fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many issues in the code fragment posted:

- you do not test the return value of `fgets()`, causing undefined behavior when accessing the buffer contents if `fgets()` failed.
- the call `fgets(sentinel,4,stdin);` will only read up to 3 bytes into `sentinel` in order to keep space for the trailing null terminator. Hence the line feed entered by the user after `yes` will stay in the input stream and cause the next call to `fgets()` to return immediately with a buffer contents of `"\n"`.
- `len = strlen(recipe.ingredients[j]) + 1;` is too large: the offset of the newline would be `strlen(recipe.ingredients[j]) - 1` if it is present and if `recipe.ingredients[j]` is not an empty string.
- `recipe.ingredients[len] == "\0";` is completely bogus: it is just a comparison, not an assignment, and it compares apples and oranges: a `char` and a `const char *`.

A simpler way to strip the newline if present is this:

```
char *p = recipe.ingredients[j];
p[strcspn(p, "\n")] = '\0';   // overwrite the newline, if present
```

Here is a modified version:

```
for (;;) {
    char sentinel[100];
    char *p;

    printf("Put the ingredient: ");
    if (!fgets(recipe.ingredients[j], 30, stdin))
        break;
    p = recipe.ingredients[j];
    p[strcspn(p, "\n")] = '\0';   // overwrite the newline, if present
    fprintf(fbr, "%s,", recipe.ingredients[j]);
    j++;
    counter++;
    printf("Do you want to continue? (yes/no): ");
    if (!fgets(sentinel, sizeof sentinel, stdin))
        break;
    if (strcmp(sentinel, "yes") != 0)
        break;
}
```

Note that you should also check that `j` does not get incremented beyond the size of the array `recipe.ingredient`.

Comment: First of all, I thank you too for the patience and your time. I was wandering if there are other alternatives than break, that's the reason why I preferred to put a do while instead of a for, but just because this is a school project and he won't let us use break for this

Comment: You are *breaking* out of your read loop on any of those conditions, so `break` is proper. You can also use `goto` instead. e.g. `goto readdone;` and then put `readdone:;` after the closing brace in the read loop. `break` is proper when breaking out of 1-loop, `goto` is *required* to jump out of nested loop in a single call.

Comment: In addition what @DavidC.Rankin wrote above, splitting "sub-tasks" into separate functions allows you more latitude on breaking/jumping out of a loop, because you can *return* from a function at any point. So, if you had a double or triple or even more complicated loop that does something, putting it into a separate function allows you to interrupt the entire nested loop (in that function) by simply returning from the function at any point you need. Splitting work into such functions makes them easier to understand for us humans, too. [...]

Comment: [...] So, @Goner, the reason `goto` and sometimes even `break` is frowned upon, is not because they are bad or anything like that, but because there is almost always a better way: more readable, easier to understand, and therefore maintainable, which is very important in practice. Usually by splitting the job at hand into separate functions. (That needs a bit of experience, though, because exactly *how* to split work into functions, is equally important.)

Comment: Far too many teachers frown upon flow control statements such as `break`, `continue`, multiple `return` statements and of course `goto`. Some coding style guides even bar them completely. It is important to understand the various possibilities that C offers so you can read other people's code. `do`/`while` loops are sometimes put forth as a way to avoid `break` from infinite loops, but in my experience, they almost always contain logic errors that are much worse problems. Your code fragment is one more such example. There are 3 reasons to exit the loop, explicit `break` statements are fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an extended comment, that might be useful to some.

The [answer by chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218464/1475978) is correct for the question stated.

I just wanted to expand a bit on the issue, and to show an alternate way that can be easily extended to trimming leading and trailing whitespace too.

The core logic is simple. We use two indexes into the string, `i` and `o`. `i` is the index of the next character to check, and `o` is the index where we save the next character we wish to keep.

Now, I prefer to use pointers rather than indexes to a character array. It does not matter much, but to me, this form (compared to the array indexing form) is easier to read and write.  I also like it because it is usually enough to trip those that grab code off internet to pass as their own homework, without understanding at all what the code does. I do enjoy tripping those cheaters, too.

---

A function that removes all leading whitespace from a string is often called `ltrim()`. Here is how one might implement that. This one also removes all control characters:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *ltrim(char *s)
{
    if (s != NULL) {
        char *in = s;
        char *out = s;

        /* Skip leading whitespace and control characters. */
        while (isspace(*in) || iscntrl(*in))
            in++;

        /* If there was no leading whitespace,
           we can simply return the original string. */
        if (in == out)
            return s;

        /* Move the rest of the string to start at s. */
        while (*in)
            *(in++) = *(out++);

        /* Terminate the string. */
        *out = '\0';
    }

    /* The function always returns the argument. */
    return s;
}
```

Note how `in` points to the next character to be examined in the string, and `out` points to the next position to store a kept character. We always have `in >= out`, i.e. we will not try to read a position we have already overwritten, because whenever we increment `out`, we also increment `in`.

There are several ways to implement `rtrim()`, a function that removes all trailing whitespace, including newline. Here is one approach. This one removes both trailing whitespace and control characters.

```
char *rtrim(char *s)
{
    if (s) {
        char *oug = s;

        /* This just implements out = s + strlen(s). */
        while (*out != '\0')
            out++;

        /* Back over trailing whitespace and controls. */
        while (out > s && (isspace(out[-1]) || iscntrl(out[-1])))
            out--;

        /* Terminate the string here. */
        *out = '\0';
    }

    /* This function also always returns the argument. */
    return s;
}
```

This time, after we have copied (or checked) all characters, we "back up" over the trailing characters we wish to remove. Because `out` points to the *next* position , the previous character is `out[-1]` (equivalent to `*(out-1)` in C). We must be careful, however, to not back over the beginning of the string.

Rather than just implement `trim()` as a call to both above functions, it is more efficient to combine them into a single function:

```
char *trim(char *s)
{
    if (s != NULL) {
        char *in = s;
        char *out = s;

        /* Skip leading whitespace and control characters. */
        while (isspace(*in) || iscntrl(*in))
            in++;

        /* Move the rest of the string to start at s. */
        while (*in)
            *(in++) = *(out++);

        /* Back up over trailing whitespace and control characters. */
        while (out > s && (isspace(out[-1]) || iscntrl(out[-1])))
            out--;

        /* Terminate the string. */
        *out = '\0';
    }

    /* Always return the argument. */
    return s;
}
```

I usually only implement `trim()`.

In some cases, you might wish to have a function that removes both leading and trailing whitespaces and control characters, but also converts all consecutive whitespace and control characters to a single space, for example to clean up some input. It is only slightly more complicated:

```
char *clean(char *s)
{
    if (s != NULL) {
        char *in = s;
        char *out = s;

        /* Skip leading whitespace and control characters. */
        while (isspace(*in) || iscntrl(*in))
            in++;

        /* Move the rest of the string to start at s,
           combining consecutive whitespaces and control
           characters to a single space. */
        while (*in)
            if (isspace(*in) || iscntrl(*in)) {
                /* Skip all consecutive whitespaces and
                   control characters first. */
                while (isspace(*in) || iscntrl(*in));
                    in++;
                /* "Replace" them with a single space. */
                *(out++) = ' ';
            } else
                *(in++) = *(out++);

        /* Back up over the one trailing space we might have copied. */
        if (out > s && out[-1] == ' ')
            out--;

        /* Terminate the string. */
        *out = '\0';
    }

    /* Always return the argument. */
    return s;
}
```

Essentially, the only difference to `trim()` is that in the copying loop, if we encounter a whitespace or control character, we skip them all (consecutive ones, that is), and then store just one space, to "replace" them with that single space.

---

Because the above functions modify the string given, you cannot use them on string literals. That is, something like

```
char *mystring = clean(" This Will Not Work ");
```

or

```
char *oldstring = " Thiss Will Not Work Either ";
char *mystring = clean(oldstring);
```

will not work, because you are not supposed to try and modify string literals. Remember that in above forms, `oldstring` and `mystring` are pointers to string literals.

Instead, create a character array that is initialized to the string literal. You are free to modify the character array afterwards:

```
char  mybuffer[] = " This will work just Fine.\n";
clean(mybuffer);
```

or

```
char  line[256] = "This will work, too.\n";
printf("Read '%s'.\n", trim(line));
```

Note how the return value (the pointer to the string) is not used in the former example, but is supplied as the string to be printed in the latter example. If you use the form used in the latter example, remember that it modifies `line[]`; the line is still "trimmed" after the printf call. Simply put, the latter is exactly equivalent to

```
char  line[256] = "This will work, too.\n";
trim(line);
printf("Read '%s'.\n", line);
```

This last form is easiest to read and understand, and therefore also to maintain, but programmers usually prefer the preceding one because it is shorter.  Hopefully, this extended comment itself is enough to show why shorter is not always better. :)

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I appreciate it